# Remove duplicates of pairs from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Part of my table looks like this:

```html
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| FN1         | LN        | FN2         |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| Geraint     | Davies    | David T. C. |
| Philip      | Davies    | David T. C. |
| David T. C. | Davies    | Philip      |
| David T. C. | Davies    | Geraint     |
| Mr Nigel    | Evans     | Graham      |
| Graham      | Evans     | Mr Nigel    |
```

It is made from joint tables where the join condition is last name (different people may have the same last names but different first names).

My question is how do I get rid of duplicates so there is always only one pair (using either FN1 or FN2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query that creates the table so that is uses

```
t1.FN < t2.FN
```

instead of

```
t1.FN != t2.FN
```

This will prevent it from returning the related rows twice.